# Base64 to bytes losing information in Node

Tags: node.js

I am using node version 6.6.0. I have a fairly big (1Mb) base64 string that I want to store in bytes in my filesystem. I use the following code:

```
myString = "abase64string.....";
data = Buffer.from(myString, "base64");
```

But when I try to check the number of bytes for `data`, the value is always the same (regardless of the image) : 262144 bytes (256kb).

Am I missing something here? Node documentation states that the maximum size for a Buffer is 1Gb.

Comment: Where is `myString` coming from? It seems like it's truncated.

Comment: Comes from a `POST` request. Measuring the size in bytes of the string has approximately 1Mb. Note that this works for smaller than 256kb strings.

Comment: Do a test without the http server. Write a simple script that reads the file from disk and base64 decode it (you may want to generate a base64 version of the file first). Sometimes other things get in the way like POST length limits or HTTP request timeout configured in the server (nginx, apache or even node http module)

Comment: @slebetman will do! FYI, the payload limit is set at 5Mb. I can see that my payload has more than 1Mb, while the base64 string as approximately 1Mb.

Comment: I meant more specifically, is `myString` actually *just* the argument passed to the response's *first* `'data'` event handler, or is `myString` the *entire* buffered response (concatenation of *all* `'data'` event chunks), or are you using the `request` module from npm which does all of this for you?

Comment: @mscdex The string was indeed truncated, the requester was sending "=" terminators every 256kb. 

FYI: I was using Hapi as a server. I access the payload property as request.payload.myString.

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by @mscdex helped solving the problem, as the string was indeed, truncated. I looked for the terminator value for a base64 string:

```
var terminator = myString.indexOf("=");
var len = myString.length;
```

and compared it with the length of the string. When I saw that the values were very disparate (more than 2 apart), I understood that the problem was not in the server.